# Search mySql and Add Results Into Form

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm trying to use the script below to return data from a mySQL into a HTML form.

```
 <?php
require("phpfile.php");  

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server  

$connection=mysql_connect ("host", $username, $password);  
if (!$connection) { die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}  

// Set the active MySQL database  

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);  
if (!$db_selected) {  
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());  
}  


$email = $_POST['email']
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$email%'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
  echo $row['forename']; 
  echo $row['surname'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
?>
```

The field which is used to match the input data to that held in my database is the email address. Basically if the keyed in email address matches a record in the database, it returns the first and surname.

However when I run it I receive the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/search.php on line 18

Where Line 18 is:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$email%'");
```

I've taken the source code from a tutorial I found on the Internet and I've been back to the source and rechecked my field names etc and I can't find out what the problem is.

Could someone perhaps take a look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$email = $_POST['email']
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$email%'");
```

change to:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$email%'");
```

you forgot the ; after declaring your $email variable.

Also, the clue here is unexpected T_VARIABLE.

Basically, unexpected means that the script was doing something and unexpectedly encountered something it shouldn't have during the process. In this case it unexpectedly encountered a variable ( T_VARIABLE ) when it was "expecting" a semi colon.

Answer (score 1):

The line above line 18 lacks a semi-colon which is causing line 18 to be parsed incorrectly.

```
$email = $_POST['email']
```

The clue is "Parse error: syntax error", which oftentimes means you have a missing semi-colon, parentheses or curly brace in a previous statement.